# css transform property not working on element as expected

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I have got a navigation side bar which expands on click of a button and contracts on clicking the same button again.

When the navigation bar is collapsed, the text on the button says **EXPAND >**

And when the navigation bar is expanded, the text on the button says **COLLAPSE <**

See this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/swagnikd/full/XeWjVR/)

Problem is the text "EXPAND" or "COLLAPSE" on the button appears horizontally while I wanted them to appear vertically like this.

[image]

I used CSS transform property the following way to rotate the text -90deg and it worked fine initially.

```
#expand, #collapse{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

But then when I wrote the following Jquery code, the text **no longer** appears rotated.

```
if( $('.option').hasClass('non-visible') ){     // Collapsed

        $('.open-menu').css('display','unset');
        $('.close-menu').css('display','none');

    } else {    // Expanded

        $('.open-menu').css('display','none');
        $('.close-menu').css('display','unset');

    }
```

Here is the HTML code for the button:

```
            <button id="button-expand">
                <p id="expand" class="open-menu">EXPAND</p>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right open-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <p id="collapse" class="close-menu">COLLAPSE</p>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left close-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <p><!-- nothing --></p>
            </button>
```

The Jquery code is required to selectively display "EXPAND" or "COLLAPSE" on the button (depending on the navigation bar whether it is expanded or collapsed).

Kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong. Is there some kind of conflict/overriding taking place?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the use of `display:unset`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `unset` values with blanks `""`. When you use `unset` it looks as if the styles go out like a chain reaction (cascading perhaps?). Anyways, when toggling between `display:none`, it's common practice to use `""` blanks because that'll trigger default `display`(`initial`)

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/01/pen/YrzNVN?editors=0010)

```
    $('.open-menu').css('display','');
    $('.close-menu').css('display','none');

} else {    // Expanded

    $('.open-menu').css('display','none');
    $('.close-menu').css('display','');
```

Answer (score 0):

> But then when I wrote the following Jquery code, the text no longer appears rotated.

**No need to change your jQuery code or HTML.**

You need simply to add to **#expand, #collapse{**:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

> [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode): The property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.
>
> **vertical-lr**: Content flows vertically from top to bottom, horizontally from left to right. The next vertical line is positioned to the right of the previous line

In this case you need to change:

```
transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

to:

```
transform: rotate(-180deg)
```

Hence your css class  is:

```
#expand, #collapse{
   font-size: 0.8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
   transform: rotate(-180deg);
   writing-mode: vertical-rl
```

}

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 // initially I want the side bar collapsed
 $('.option').addClass('non-visible');
 $('.dropdown').slideUp(0);
 $('.side-dropdown').slideUp(0);

 dowork();

 $('#button-expand').click(function(){

  $('.option').toggleClass('non-visible');
  dowork();
 });

 listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
 for(i = 0; i < listItems.length - 3 ; i ++){  

  listItems[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){   
   if( $('.option').hasClass('non-visible') ){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var dropdown_id = id+"-submenu";
    $(`#side-${dropdown_id}`).slideDown('medium');
   } 
   else {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var dropdown_id = id+"-submenu";
    $(`#${dropdown_id}`).slideDown('medium');
   }
  });

  listItems[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
   if( $('.option').hasClass('non-visible') ){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var dropdown_id = id+"-submenu";
    $(`#side-${dropdown_id}`).slideUp(0);
   } 
   else {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var dropdown_id = id+"-submenu";
    $(`#${dropdown_id}`).slideUp(0);
   }
  });
 }
})

var dowork = function(){

 if( $('.option').hasClass('non-visible') ){  // Collapsed
  
  $('.open-menu').css('display','unset');
  $('.close-menu').css('display','none');

 } else { // Expanded
  
  $('.open-menu').css('display','none');
  $('.close-menu').css('display','unset');

 }
}
```

```css
.container-fluid > .row > .col-md-12 {
 padding: 0;
 height: 100vh; 
}

.left-panel{
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #34495e;
 position: relative;
}

#upper-list{
 list-style: none;
 /*float: left;*/
 padding: 0;
}

#upper-list > li{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;

 /*border: 1px solid orange;*/
}

#upper-list > li:nth-child(1){
 margin-top: 0.5em;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#upper-list > li:hover,
#lower-list > li:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}

#upper-list > li:hover > div,
#upper-list > li:hover > div > i,
#lower-list > li:hover > div,
#lower-list > li:hover > div > i {
 color: #FFC300;
}

.user-image-container{
 width: 4em;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.user-image{
 height: 3em;
 width: 3em;
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-radius: 50%;

 background-image: url('http://www.mrbeantvseries.co.uk/bean3.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#person_name{
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 /*border: 1px solid lightblue;*/
}

.icon-container{
 padding: 0.6em 2em;
 float: left;
 width: 4em;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;

 /*border: 1px solid skyblue;*/
}

.icon-container > i {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: white;
}

.option{
 padding: 0.5em 1em;
 float: left;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
 color: white;

 /*border: 1px solid skyblue;*/
}

.dropdown{
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%; 
}

.side-dropdown{
 position: absolute;
 left: 4em;
 top: 0;
  width: 160px;

 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;

 box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px lightgrey,
    2px -2px 5px lightgrey; 
}

.dropdown > li,
.side-dropdown > li {
 padding: 0.4em 1em;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu' , serif;
 background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.dropdown > li:hover,
.side-dropdown > li:hover{
 background-color: lightgrey;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#button-expand{
 /*position: relative;*/
 height: 100%;
 width: 1.5em; /*requied to contain the expand text*/
 color: #807F7F;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #C1C1C1,#F3F3F3); 
}

#button-expand:focus{
 outline: 0;
}

#expand, #collapse{
 font-size: 0.8em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    writing-mode: vertical-rl
}

.non-visible{
 display: none;
}

#lower-list{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#lower-list > li{
 margin-bottom: 0!important;
 float: left;
}

.square{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;

 border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-top: 0.4em solid #34495e;
 border-left: 0.4em solid transparent;
 border-right: 0.4em solid transparent;
}

.side-square{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1em;

 border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-left: 0.35em solid #34495e;
 border-right: 0.2em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:400,700|PT+Sans:400,700|Ubuntu">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="left-panel">
                <ul id="upper-list">

                    <li>
                        <div class="user-image-container">
                            <div class="user-image">
                                <!-- picture inserted here -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <p id="person_name">Mr. Bean</p>
                            <p id="person_email">mrbean@gmail.com</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li id="contacts">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            CONTACTS
                        </div>

                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-contacts-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="contacts-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="products">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            PRODUCTS
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-products-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Product templates</li>
                            <li>Products</li>
                            <li>Categories</li>
                            <li>Attributes</li>
                            <li>Tree nodes</li>
                            <li>Gift card</li>
                            <li>Bill of materials (BOM)</li>
                            <li>Price lists</li>
                            <li>Product suppliers</li>
                            <li>Attribute sets</li>
                            <li>Reports</li>
                            <li>Import product locations</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="products-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Product templates</li>
                                        <li>Products</li>
                                        <li>Categories</li>
                                        <li>Attributes</li>
                                        <li>Tree nodes</li>
                                        <li>Gift card</li>
                                        <li>Bill of materials (BOM)</li>
                                        <li>Price lists</li>
                                        <li>Product suppliers</li>
                                        <li>Attribute sets</li>
                                        <li>Reports</li>
                                        <li>Import product locations</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="sales">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            SALES
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-sales-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="sales-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="purchase">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            PURCHASE
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-purchase-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="purchase-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="shipping">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            SHIPPING
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-shipping-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="shipping-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="inventoryNstock">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            INVENTORY & STOCK
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-inventoryNstock-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="inventoryNstock-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="production">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-bullseye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            PRODUCTION
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-production-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="production-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="financial">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-building" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            FINANCIAL
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-financial-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="financial-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="settings">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            SETTINGS
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-settings-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="settings-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>

                    <li id="administration">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            ADMINISTRATION
                        </div>
                        <ul class="side-dropdown" id="side-administration-submenu">
                            <div class="side-square"></div>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                            <li>Option 6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                                    <!-- sub menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown" id="administration-submenu">
                                        <div class="square"></div>
                                        <li>Option 1</li>
                                        <li>Option 2</li>
                                        <li>Option 3</li>
                                    </ul>
                </ul>

                <ul id="lower-list">
                    <li>
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <button id="button-expand">
                <p id="expand" class="open-menu">EXPAND</p>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right open-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <p id="collapse" class="close-menu">COLLAPSE</p>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left close-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <p><!-- nothing --></p>
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```